# Passing and Reading values using child_process spawn in node js

Tags: php, node.js, environment-variables, child-process, spawn

I am Developing a Node js Application in which i need to invoke and execute a .php file and i have implemented it successfully, but the problem is when i am trying to send values to php file i am unable to read it.

Here is the sample code that i am using to invoke a php file

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn
    router.post('/textphp', function(req, res){
        var php = spawn('/usr/bin/php',['./public_html/files/demo_php_script.php'],
            {
                env:
                {
                    foo: "value"
                }
            });
        php.stdout.on('data', function(data)
        {
            console.log(data.toString());
        });
    });
```

And here is the format i which i am trying to read the passed data in a php file

```
<?php
   echo $_ENV['foo']
?>
```

I have searched every where and i cannot find a solution, any response will be greatly thankful.

Comment: Is your path './public_html/files/demo_php_script.php' correct? Try to catch php.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

Comment: @lurii my path is correct when I am invoking the node js path the PHP file is getting invoked and all the remaining operations are getting carried away except this variable is not getting read

Comment: Please check your variables_order (http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) if it includes letter 'E'

Comment: I have resolved the issue by using "exec-php" npm module in the form of calling a function. Thanks for your help.